# Gradle is not building the app on the emulator

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-emulator

i'm trying to run my app on my mobile(emulator) , this is not the first time i already ran this app on my mobile . but this time it asked me to uninstall the app, i did so then it's printing this one the screen DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: disable instant run

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 2.3

Disable Instant Run

Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Instant Run

**Edit: To Disable Instant run**

In Windows:

Open Find Action: Control + Shift + A.
Search instant run and open instant run under settings.
Uncheck Enable instant run...

In Mac:

Open Find Action: Command + Shift + A.
Search instant run and open instant run under settings.
Uncheck Enable instant run...

Answer (score -1):

**plz follow the below step**

1 - Build -> Clean Project->Rebuild Project
or

open terminal and type gradlew clean

Comment: you will find terminal somewhere side of logcat ,Build and terminal . click on terminal and type  gradlew clean

Comment: if you are having enable instant run  plz go setting -> Buld,Execution,Deployment-> and uncheck rhe checkbox of Enable intant run to hot swap code

Comment: if you are still getting problem please let me know

Comment: I have more solution of this problem please let me know if you are getting stuck